# My hibernate mapping files exist, what are possible reasons that the mapping can't be found?

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, eclipse-plugin, hibernate-tools

I dynamically generated my hbms.  Now when I attempt to use the HQL Editor in Eclipse, I'm getting the following error:

Hibernate Dynamic SQL Window:
HQL was valid, but no SQL generated. Your configuration most likely does not have any mappings defined.

Hibernate Query Result Window:
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: system is not mapped [from system].

My hql reads:

from com.kevin.hibernate.Address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you create your **Hibernate Console Configuration**? Did you declare a `hibernate.cfg.xml`? If yes, does it list the mappings? Do you get any useful hint in the **Error View**?

Maybe following the steps of the section [3.3. Creating a Hibernate Console configuration](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/2.0.0.GA/hibernatetools/en/html/plugins.html#d0e434) will help.

#### References

- Hibernate Tools Reference Guide

  - [Chapter 3. Eclipse Plugins](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/2.0.0.GA/hibernatetools/en/html/plugins.html)

Comment: Thanks for the help.  My configuration was not set up correctly.  I created a new one using the hibernate.cfg.xml file that was created the first time and it now works.